# I just cloned a project from github and when I have tried to run {composer install} in visual studio I got this error

Tags: github

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- "https://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:x-oauth-basic@github.com/cartalyst/data-gri   
  d.git" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-github.com-cartalyst-data-grid.git/"                                               
                                                                                                                                          
  Cloning into bare repository 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-github.com-cartalyst-data-grid.git'...                       
  remote: Repository not found.                                                                                                           
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/cartalyst/data-grid.git/' not found                                                               
                                                                                                                                          

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong URL. https://github.com/cartalyst/data-grid.git does not exist, correct is https://github.com/cartalyst/demo-data-grid.git (notice the *demo*)